# Windows Virtual Environments vs. Linux Virtual Environments in Handling Relative Imports

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-import

In almost all of the project I've worked on, I've kept a file structure like this:

```
Project
|.vscode
|project_venv
||defs.py
|source
||[a bunch of scripts that depend on defs.py]
|typings
```

In the virtual environments I made in Windows, this worked fine, since I could handle that import with `import defs as d` from any other script or module in `source` without issue.

However, when I switched my OS to Linux (MX-21, a Debian distro), the newly created venvs I made for my projects, following this file hierarchy, broke the imports. Hacking this with `sys` is one solution I've seen here. Unfortunately, thanks to `autopep8`, the import statements get resorted and the import still fails.

I've read through the Python documentation and other recommended solutions here, and none of its standards for relative importing (e.g. `from <dots and directory references of various kinds> import defs as d`) worked correctly.

What do I have to do differently with Linux-built virtual environments to get that one relative import working again?

Comment: changing system doesn't need to change imports. But changing `Current Working Directory` (changing folder in which you start script) can makes problem. And I see `.vscode` which suggests that you was using `VS Code` - and it could start script with different `Current Working Directory`. You should check it with `print( os.getcwd() )`. I think I saw few question where problem was `VS Code` because it was running code from wrong folder.

Comment: @furas , thank you. I'll look into it. I did find a workaround which I'll post now, though it's janky.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there is a janky workaround that `autopep8` won't overcorrect and that won't throw a major error:

```
import sys
# Import all of the other stuff that imports normally.

if bool(1):
    sys.path.insert(1, '/directory/holding/defs')
    import defs as d
```

I also moved the path of `defs.py` to `source`, but that was just to avoid the hassle of moving `defs.py` before deleting and recreating virtual environments.